Proving that operator in $L^2[0,1]$ is compact
I need help with some functional analysis:
Let $A$ be a continuous linear operator on $L^2[0,1]$ and for any $f \in L^2[0,1]$ the function $Af$ is Lipschitz continuous. Show that $A$ is compact.
It is obvious that $\mathrm{Im}\, A \subset C[0,1]$ and that should be the only use of Lipschitz continuity here.
I was told that the following theorem might help here, but still don't know how to use it: let a banach space $X$ be reflexive and $X^*$ separable (both hold for $L^2[0,1]$), then the unit ball is weakly sequentially compact, i.e. every sequence in $\{x: \|x\| \leq 1\}$ has a weakly convergent subsequence.
Thanks for any tips!

Recall that the space of Lipschitz continuous functions on $[0, 1]$, $C^{0, 1}([0, 1])$, is a Banach space under the norm:
$$\|f\|_{C^{0, 1}} = \|f\|_\infty + \sup_{x \neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|}$$
Then $A$ can be regarded as an operator from $L^2([0, 1])$ to $C^{0, 1}([0, 1])$. We note that it is closed. Indeed, if $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ and $Af_n \to g$ in $C^{0, 1}([0, 1])$, then in particular $Af_n \to g$ uniformly, so $Af_n \to g$ in $L^2$. But $A$ is $L^2$-to-$L^2$ continuous, whence $Af_n \to Af$ in $L^2$. Thus, $Af = g$, i.e., $A$ is closed. By the closed graph theorem, $A$ is bounded. Hence, there exists $C > 0$ and $D > 0$ s.t. for any $f$ with $\|f\|_{L^2} \leq 1$, we have $Af$ is uniformly bounded by $C$ and Lipschitz continuous with constant $D$. Thus, by Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, $A(B_1)$ is precompact in $C([0, 1])$, where $B_1$ is the closed unit ball of $L^2([0, 1])$. Since the natural inclusion $C([0, 1]) \hookrightarrow L^2([0, 1])$ is continuous, we have $A(B_1)$ is precompact in $L^2([0, 1])$, i.e., $A$ is compact.

+1 Nice. ${}{}$

(+) Well done. -

@David I tried applying Arzelà–Ascoli, but got stumped with the inclusion $C([0,1]) \hookrightarrow L^2([0,1])$ preserving precompactness — it is not quite clear because the inclusion is not compact (functions $e_n(x) = \sqrt{2} \sin (2 \pi n x)$
form a bounded set in $C([0,1])$, but they do not admit a convergent sub-sequence in $L^2([0,1])$, as they form an orthonormal set). Could you add more detail, please?

@Plumbum What is important is not whether the inclusion map is compact, but that it is continuous. This is because any continuous map between metric spaces maps precompact subsets to precompact subsets.

@Dean Thank you! Managed to prove it right now. The only thing left bothering me is why $A(B_1)$ is uniformly equicontinuous (needed to apply Arzelà–Ascoli theorem). As David Gao said, each function $Af$ is indeed Lipschitz continuous with some constant, but these constants are different for each $Af$ and it is not clear how to get the definition of  $A(B_1)$ being uniformly equicontinuous — if, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\left|Af(x) - Af(y)\right| < \varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ for all functions $Af$ with $|f|_{L^2} \leq 1$).

@Plumbum since $A$ is bounded from $L^2$ to $C^{0,1}$ you get that for $|f|2 \le 1$ the norm $|Af|{C^{0,1}}$ is bounded so that there is a constant $D$ independent of $f$ such that $Af$ is $D$-Lipschitz. In particular, $A(B_1)$ is equi-continuous.

@Plumbum As Evangelopoulos Foivos mentioned, the constants $C$ and $D$ in the answer are independent of $f$, and apply to all $Af$ with $|f|_2 \leq 1$. $C$ provides the uniform boundedness required in Arzelà–Ascoli and $D$ provides the uniform equicontinuity.

@David Thank you for your neat solution and everybody else who helped me understand it!
